# How to get items to drop as opposed to being side by side in the nav bar - bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Forgive me if this is a simple question, I'm new to bootstrap 4 and wasn't able to find the answer searching online.

I have a nav bar that is laid out in three columns, logo to the left, small menu in the middle and a logout button to the right.

When I get down to the 550px to 767px screen size, instead of dropping a line, it's just squishing everything and running off the page, I've tried turning off every style in the console but nothing is changing. The only way I've gotten it to work is to remove the navbar class from the nav element, but that breaks the page in every other screen size so that's not the answer.

Here is my HTML code, can someone point me in the right direction? the out come I'm looking for is similar to this (logo above the menus)-

Logo

Menu 1 | Menu 2 | Menu 3 | Menu 4                           Logout

html:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Logo</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Name
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu text-center dropdown-logout" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <form action="" method="post">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Logout</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link btn-ghost-blue" href="/#">Menu 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link btn-ghost-blue" href="/#">Menu 2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link btn-ghost-blue" href="/#">Menu 3</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link btn-ghost-blue" href="/#">Menu 4</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Thank You!

Comment: in that case, u need to use the bootstraps grid system to break your divs into new line when the screen size reduces. check this url https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: ok, I added a col col-lg around the navbar-brand and one to the navbar-collapse, and it didn't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to use bootstrap 4 responsive navbar from documentation since you don't want to collapse your navbar on small screen. So you might design your own responsive navbar.

Like comment suggested, using the grid system to adjust your col-size for different screen sizes. The following code can give you a idea, run it in full screen and resize your window.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-light flex-nowrap flex-row">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row w-100">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-auto">
        <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">Logo</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-auto">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav flex-row">
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link pr-3" href="">Login</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Sign up</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```